# Accessing IIS Site After Moving Domain

Tags: windows, iis

I am in the process of migrating from IIS with to another platform. The company will still need access to the old site and associated Database for a while. The server is currently hosted on AWS EC2. I am trying to figure out the best way to do this. Unfortunately, there are a mix of relative and absolute links on the site, so I don't think a subdomain would work reliably. There are way too many links to change and would also entail modifying queries. I have thought of changing the hosts file on the server to point to itself for the domain. the users will use the IP address to access the server initially.

Comment: This has little to do with programming. Set up a reverse proxy in front, so that you can move traffic based on certain rules to gradually migrate all users to a new place. That allows a transparent migration in most cases, and users don't have to change their URLs (using IP addresses is just horrible in modern days).

Answer (score 0):

To allow access to the old site, you can set up a reverse proxy on the new platform to forward requests for the old site to the IIS server hosting the old site. This way, users can continue to use the existing URLs to access the old site without changing all links.

You need to set up a new server on the new platform as a reverse proxy, then configure the reverse proxy to forward requests to the EC2 instance hosting the old site, and return the response to the user. Don't forget that you need to update your old site's DNS settings to point to the new reverse proxy server's IP address.

When you have completed the migration and the old site is no longer needed, you can simply deactivate the IIS server hosting the old site and delete the reverse proxy configuration on the new platform.